# How to use JMESPath to filter array of object based on contains of value in subproperty arrary

Tags: json, jmespath

How use JMESPath to filter nodes that possess email receivers with exact email?
I have JSON object:

```
   [     
     {
        "test":1,
        "emailReceivers": [
          {
            "emailAddress": "a1@abc.com",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test":2,
        "emailReceivers": [
          {
            "emailAddress": "a2@abc.com",
          },
          {
            "emailAddress": "a3@abc.com",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I would like to get node after filtering by elememailReceivers that contains `a1@abc.com`:

```
     {
        "test":1,
        "emailReceivers": [
          {
            "emailAddress": "a1@abc.com",
          }
        ]
      }
```

I was trying to use documentation https://jmespath.org/ and examples but I failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use [`contains`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains) on a filter and ask sub-keys containing a certain value.

With the query

```
[?contains(emailReceivers[].emailAddress, 'a1@abc.com')]
```

This will give:

```json
[
  {
    "test": 1,
    "emailReceivers": [
      {
        "emailAddress": "a1@abc.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

On your example array:

```json
[     
  {
    "test":1,
    "emailReceivers": [
      {
        "emailAddress": "a1@abc.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test":2,
    "emailReceivers": [
      {
        "emailAddress": "a2@abc.com"
      },
      {
        "emailAddress": "a3@abc.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```